# Spring @ModelAttribute Convert formatted number to Double

Tags: java, spring, modelandview

```
//Entity
public class MyEntity {
  private Double amount;
  public Double getAmount() { return this.amount; }
  public void setAmount(Double value) { this.amount = value; }
}

//Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/save")
public void save(MyEntity a) {
   //save to db
}

//
<input name="amount" value="1,252.00" />
```

When I summit form it's keep return `400 - Bad Request`.. and I find out it's because spring unable to convert formatted number to Double. How to convert request before set into `MyEntity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm implements Conversion class that extends `CustomNumberEditor`

```
public class MyCustomNumberEditor extends CustomNumberEditor {
   public void MyCustomNumberEditor(Class numberClass, boolean allowEmpty) {
      this.numberClass = numberClass;
      this.allowEmpty = allowEmpty;
   }

   @Override
   public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
      if (this.allowEmpty && !StringUtils.hasText(text)) {
      // Treat empty String as null value.
      setValue(null);
      }
      else {
         try {
            setValue(Convert.to(this.numberClass, text));
         }
         catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse date: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And Insert these into controller

```
@InitBinder
public void initDataBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
   binder.registerCustomEditor(Double.class, new MyCustomNumberEditor(Double.class));
}
```

Comment: is it possible to only isolate to a specific ModelAttribute instead of setting it up globally?

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
public class MyEntity {
  private Double amount;
  public Double getAmount() { return this.amount; }
  public void setAmount(Double value) { this.amount = value; }
}

//Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/save")
public void save(HttpServletRequest request) {
   Double doubleVal=Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("amount"));
   MyEntity myEnt=new MyEntity();
   myEnt.setAmount(doubleVal);
   //save to db
}

//
<input name="amount" value="1,252.00" />
```

As you are not sending the whole model attribute but just a value, this should work for you.

Alternatively you can specify `@ModelAttrubute` in your spring form and catch it on `save` method.

Comment: There's no Spring solution? `@Converter` or `@Binder`, `MyEntity` may be have many properties.

Comment: @BooBooBear [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) might help you.